# access variable in scope from ng-repeat ng-style

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-style

I got some problem on AngularJS.
my controller, mainCtrl, has this variables :

```
this.colors = {Sam:blue,Jane:red,Tom:pink};
this.arr = [{person:'Sam',story:'some story'},{name:'Tom',story:'some story2'}]
```

And I got this code :

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
<ul ng-repeat="obj in arr">
<li ng-style={color:vm.color[obj.person]}>{{obj.story}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want that the li will be colored such as the color of the person at colors dictionary . how can I handle that? I got undefined every time, but when I do it explictly its work , for Example :

```
<li ng-style={color:vm.color['Sam']}>{{obj.story}}</li>
```

Comment: is arr is undefined or obj ?

Comment: It seems that you defined this.colors at first and then use it as color (without the final 's')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this.

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
   <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="obj in vm.arr track by $index" 
           ng-style="{'color':vm.colors[obj.person]}"
           ng-bind="obj.story">
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

1. Remember to use your alias `vm` (controllerAs)
2. Use`track by` with `ng-repeat` for better performance.
3. I think that `ng-repeat` should have been placed in `li`

Her's a working `jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/irhabi/nh4ddemr/

Comment: still not working .. I think that the problem is that it cant identify obj.person, because if i replace it with "Sam" its work properly

Comment: @Chenko47 look at my jsfiddle above

Answer (score 1):

You are using the controllerAs-Syntax, so you must use `vm.arr` in your ng-repeat. And furthermore you should use the ng-repeat on the list item:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="obj in vm.arr" ng-style="{color:vm.color[obj.person]}">{{obj.story}}</li>
</ul>
```